# Django 'failed connection' between two containers

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to make a connection between two of my docker containers (The requesting container running Gunicorn/Django and the api container running kroki).

I've had a look at other answers but seem to be coming up blank with a solution, so was hoping for a little poke in the right direction.

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./my_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile -
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 kroki
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - app
  kroki:
    image: yuzutech/kroki
    ports:
      - 7331:8000

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")
```

Requesting code in django

```
url = 'http://kroki:7331/bytefield/svg/' + base64_var
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            return response.text
        except ConnectionError as e:
            print("Connection to bytefield module, unavailable")
            return None
```

I'm able to access both containers via my browser successfully, however initiating the code for an internal call between the two throws out

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='kroki', port=7331): Max retries exceeded with url: /bytefield/svg/<API_URL_HERE> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f286f5ecaf0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I've had a go accessing the url via localhost:7331 & 127.0.0.1:7331 however neither seem to help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access to other containers within the same `network` you don't have to access to them using the exposed port in the `host` but using instead the actual port where the application within the container is listening.

I made a really simple example so you can understand what's your problem:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
  kroki:
    image: yuzutech/kroki
    ports:
      - 7331:8000
```

**From Host**

```
❯ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" localhost:7331

200
```

**From App**

```
/ # wget kroki:7331
Connecting to kroki:7331 (172.18.0.3:7331)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.18.0.3): Connection refused
/ # wget kroki:8000
Connecting to kroki:8000 (172.18.0.3:8000)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |************************************************************************| 51087  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

Comment: Ah. Lifesaver! That's worked a treat. 

Many thanks for the example to explain, that makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: That works using the default network or how did you start them, using a user defined network? :)